# Is there a way of getting cells to refer to their own positions

Tags: excel

I am using a formula to sort a long list into sub headings.
EG:

```
Letter     | A              | B
| -------- | -------------- |
| A        | 1              |0
| B        | 0              |1
```

and so on.
I am using a match offset formula
`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1$,A2)),1,0)`
where A2 is the cell I want to see if it contains the letter held in B1

Now I have roughly 70 different categories to go through, and don't want to have to change B$1$ for each. I was hoping I could do it automatically. However, I cannot leave it without dollar signs as it will then stop searching for "A" when is drag it downwards.
Is there a way to drag the cells across and down without having to change each row, but change for each column change? i.e B$1$ turns to C$1$ when going across, but while dragging down only A2 changes

I have tried using `cell("address"(b$1$` but that just pushes the issue further along.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you're using [absolute cell references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excelformulas/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/1/) to stop your formulas from changing when you drag or copy them around - this is correct as far as I can tell.

Notice there are two `$` signs - for example, the absolute reference to cell A1 would be `$A$1`. The first $ makes the column absolute, and the second fixes the row.

So, if you have a formula where you want the column to change but not the row, use `A$1`. If you want to fix the reference to column A but possibly change rows, it would be `$A1`.

see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) for the official microsoft page about it.